# Why is the slide attack called a generic attack if it depends on each round being the same?

Tags: cryptanalysis

From reading the answers on this website, a generic attack is one that works on all block ciphers (e.g., brute force). The slide attack does not work if the round functions are different, whether they are using different round keys, using different round constants, or are different functions altogether. Yet, I see that the slide attack is called a generic attack. Why?

Comment: Generic attacks work against ciphers having the same general structure like Feistel ciphers or substitution–permutation networks (SPN), without looking at the specific S-boxes or permutations. Having all rounds identical is also a structural property that leads to a vulnerablility independent of how the other details are chosen.

Comment: @jp So the slide attack works even if the round functions are different?

Comment: Having all rounds the same is the structural property for which the generic (i.e. independent of specific S-boxes etc) attack "slide attack" works.

Comment: @jp That isn't much clearer.

Comment: My second comment was just an answer to your response asking if the opposite of parts of what I wrote is true, so I just repeated that part in different words (instead of writing NO!).